# How to add string to a specific value? Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

| Col1 | Col2 | NewCol1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ora | 1234 | 300/1234 |
| Ora | 0123 | 300/0123 |
| APP | 0005 | 100/0005 |
| Ora | 7778 | 300/7778 |
| APP | 9999 | 100/9999 |

If I want to create a new Col with the number from Col 2 depending on the Col 1 Values. How can I do this?

- If it's ORA, then add 300|with the col2 number
- When it is APP, then add 100|with the col2 number

Eventually, I want to have

- 300|1234
- 300|0123
- 100|0005
- 300|7778
- 100|9999

df = df.withColunm('NewCol1', F.when(F.col('Col1' == Ora)), '|','300','Col2').otherwise('100','Col2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "concat" function to combine column value

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
# Define schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('Col1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Col2', StringType(), True)
])

# Original data
data = [
    {'Col1': 'Ora', 'Col2': '1234'},
    {'Col1': 'Ora', 'Col2': '0123'},
    {'Col1': 'APP', 'Col2': '0005'},
    {'Col1': 'Ora', 'Col2': '7778'},
    {'Col1': 'APP', 'Col2': '9999'}
]

# Create df from original data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Add the new column using concat and when
df1 = df.withColumn(
    'NewCol1',
    concat(
        when(df['Col1'] == 'Ora', lit('300|')).
        when(df['Col1'] == 'APP', lit('100|')),
        df['Col2']
    )
)

# Show the contents of the DataFrame
df1.show()

+----+----+--------+
|Col1|Col2| NewCol1|
+----+----+--------+
| Ora|1234|300|1234|
| Ora|0123|300|0123|
| APP|0005|100|0005|
| Ora|7778|300|7778|
| APP|9999|100|9999|
+----+----+--------+
```